# Find the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ on $\Bbb R$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Find the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function $Mf$ of the $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ function $f=\chi_{[-1,1]}$.

How do we find $Mf(x)$ for $|x| > 1$?
I see that it should decrease like $1/x$, but I can't find the formula.

Comment: For future reference, it might be valuable to specify that this is the *Hardy-Littlewood maximal function*. There are actually many maximal functions that are studied in harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on $\mathbb{R}$, the maximal function looks like:

$$ Mf(x)=\sup_{B(x,\epsilon)}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{B(x,\epsilon)}\vert f\vert dx\\
=\sup_{\epsilon}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\lambda(B(x,\epsilon)\cap [-1,1])
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

If $\vert x\vert>1$, the sup should (though this would require an argument) occur when you take your ball to include all of $[-1,1]$ and nothing more - i.e. take $\epsilon=\vert x\vert+1$.  Your maximal function will then be $Mf(x)=\frac{1}{\vert x\vert+1}$.